# Angular ui-grid, refresh check boxes after a delete

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Given a ui grid with two columns:

```
columnDefs: [
{
    name: 'select', displayName: '', cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox">'
},
{
    field: 'name', displayName: 'Item Name'
}]
```

In the delete method, I remove from the grid's data collection any items checked by the user. But the check boxes remain checked for some reason. So this:

[X] Item 1

[ ] Item 2

Turns into this after Item 1 is deleted from the grid:

[X] Item 2

How do I get that check box cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not yet faced any such issues in my Ui-grid implementation. I once faced a issue wherein When I selected all the rows and deleted them, After deletion the `selectAll` checkbox was still checked.

Based on my research efforts at that time. I guess the following work around should work for you. You can use:

`$scope.gridApi.selection.clearSelectedRows()` immediately after your deletion. This should un-check any rows if selected.

But for above to work you should already be having something like:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
}
```

which is a way to get hold of ui-grid `$scope`.

For more on this you can look up here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/426